# Bootstrap to hide popover need press button twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.7

I need to click twice to hide a popover.

I have problem like this https://jsfiddle.net/hik200/ejxkv8hb/1/

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.popover', function (e) {
$(e.target).data("bs.popover").inState.click = false; });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejxkv8hb/2/), you were adding the click listener once on your button click, which did not actually trigger the close function :

```
    function ClosePopover() {
$("#destroy").click(function(){
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('hide');


});
console.log('asd');
}
```

this is good :

```
function ClosePopover() {
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('hide');
    console.log('asd')
}
```